# Why is dataframe.sum(axis=0) getting NAN's when every value in every column is a real number?

Tags: python, pandas

All column values in the selected `measure_cols` of the `dfm` DataFrame are real numbers - in fact all are between `[-1.0..1.0]` inclusive.

Following gives `False` for all Series/Columns in the `dfc` dataframe

```
[print(f"{c}: {dfc[c].hasnans}") for c in dfc.columns]
```

Results: all `False`

But all row sums in  `dfc['shap_sum']` are coming up as `NAN`'s.  Why would this be?

```
dfc['shap_sum'] = dfc[measure_cols].sum(axis=0)
```

[image]

**Update** The following has the correct results - as seen in the debugger

```
dfc[measure_cols].sum(axis=0)
```

But when assigned to a new column in the dataframe they get distorted into `NaN`'s.

[image]

Why is this happening ?

```
dfc['shap_sum'] = dfc[measure_cols].sum(axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check the column values in `dfc` or `dfm` ?

Comment: `dfm` is actually already just the `dfc[measure_cols]` so i updated the code above to avoid the confusion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh I made the mistake of using `axis=0` intending to do `row` sums. But it's `axis=1` to do row sums.  I will never agree with that decision on polarity.